# How to pre-select an e-mail profile when opening Outlook from Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I send an e-mail based on an Excel sheet using VBA code.

I have three e-mail profiles so I am prompted to choose a profile before Outlook opens.  When I open Outlook normally I am asked to chose one of the three profiles.
[image: The picture is from the prompt I get when executing the VBA code.]

How can I pre-select the profile, so I am not prompted every time?

It works if Outlook is open from the beginning.

Also, how do I delete the PDF after I have attached the PDF to the e-mail?

```vb
Sub SendPDF()

    ChDir "D:\"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "D:\Order Form.pdf", _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Dim OutlookApp As Object
    Dim OutlookMailitem As Object
    Dim myAttachments As Object

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set OutlookMailitem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Set myAttachments = OutlookMailitem.Attachments

    With OutlookMailitem
        .To = "test@test.com"
        .Subject = "Order Form"
        '.send
        .display
        .htmlbody = "Dear Sir/Madam" & .htmlbody
        myAttachments.Add "D:\Order Form.pdf"
    End With

    Set OutlookMailitem = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see any line in your code that can prompt you to ask for a Outlook Profile. Is this the Complete Code ? What kind of prompt appears, can you paste the screenshot.

Comment: Hi. Thank your for your reply. Yes, it is the complete code. When I open Outlook normally I am asked to chose one of three profiles. One is work, one is private and the last also has to do with work. The same promt comes now with VBA, but I would like to pre- chose/select the profile (it will be sent from the same profile everytime - so no need for the promt). I will enclose a picture when I figure out how.

Comment: Sounds like you need the NameSpace.Logon method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.logon